# bq load data type when source data type in csv does not match table

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

beginner on the `bigquery` side

the question is whether `bq load` have function to ignore row when the csv data does not match schema.

we have daily customer file from cloud storage and we want to load into one table in `gcp`.
we are using airflow to do the etl.

the first task of airlfow is to use bq bash to load the `csv` file into table. however, recent, the source csv file have inconsistent data. for example, some row are `string` while the table is `int`.date is in different format where bq does not accept (can not believe bq only accept `YYYY-MM-DD` one foramt

want to know what is best way to
we can just ignore that row when the datatype does not match. I did not found good solution from bq command line doc

```
bq load --schema=***.json --skip_leading_rows=1 --replace --source_format=CSV prod*** gs://consolidated_report.csv
```

error messgae:

```
[2023-03-21 21:03:52,319] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'trust-and-
[2023-03-21 21:03:52,319] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO ****
199523:bqjob_rd35695a650af401_0000018705fc418b_1': Error while reading
[2023-03-21 21:03:52,319] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - data, error message: Could not parse '11/20/2022' as DATE for field disputeDt
[2023-03-21 21:03:52,319] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - (position 1) starting at location 276  with message 'Unable to parse' File:
[2023-03-21 21:03:52,319] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - ****.csv
```

checked the document https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#details_of_loading_csv_data but does not find anything I can direct to use

what is good/suggested way to handle the issue. I can think of is to use python to clean file first and them load into the table.

(`autodetect` is not good option. I tried but also fail since some row is different than the other)

Comment: Do you think a `--max_bad_records` parameter can be tried in your case?

Comment: I do not want to use that solution considering I am not sure how many bad record there will be

Comment: Obviously I don’t know your case context and details. Is it possible that all records are bad? And can you choose some big number, bigger than the maximum possible number of records in your files?

Comment: One option is create external table with file that doesn't match the schema in BQ table and then SELECT only the columns from the external table that matches with the BQ table. hope this helps

Comment: I think it is because 20 is not a valid month number in the date field. I don't know _BigQuery_, but I guess that you can specify there somehow how your date field is formatted.

Comment: @MichaelLi can you check my updated answer please ? I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

**- Solution 1 : if you don't have transformation between GCS and BigQuery**

You can use a built in operator `GCSToBigQueryOperator`, instead of using a `bash` command with `Airflow`. In this operator, there is a parameter `ignore_unknown_values` that allows to ignore extra fields :

```py
with airflow.DAG(
        'dag_id',
        default_args=your_args,
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:
    your_task = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id='load_gcs_to_bq',
        bucket=your_source_bucket,
        source_objects=['folder/*.csv.gz'],
        destination_project_dataset_table='project_id:your_dataset.your_table',
        source_format='CSV',
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        create_disposition='CREATE_NEVER',
        write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
        schema_object="gs://bucket/path/your_sqchema.json",
        field_delimiter=',',
        autodetect=False,
        ignore_unknown_values=True
    )
```

In this operator I given :

- The source bucket
- The wilcard for source objects and input files
- The CSV format
- The `Json` schema of `BigQuery` table from a bucket
- The `ignore_unknown_values` set to `True` to ignore unknown fields

**- Solution 2 : if you have transformation between GCS and BigQuery**

```py
import io

import airflow
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery, storage

from process_anonymization.config import settings

with airflow.DAG(
        'dag_id',
        default_args=settings.common.default_dag_args,
        schedule_interval=None) \
        as dag:
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket("bucket")
    blob = bucket.blob("your_csv.csv")
    data = blob.download_as_bytes()
    df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(data))

    # Apply your transformation on Dataframe.

    client = bigquery.Client()
    job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(df, 'dataset.table')
    job.result()
```

- In this solution, I loaded the `GCS` `CSV` file as a `Dataframe` with `storage` client and `panda`
- Then applicate the needed transformations in the `Dataframe`
- Load this `Dataframe` to the output `BigQuery` table with `BigQuery` client

Comment: Thank you for you reply. Ignore unknow value is for additional columns , right? My case is different. The number of column is right. But the data in int column is string for example

Comment: In this case, I think you have to apply an intermediate transformation before to save data to `BigQuery`. I am going to propose you another approach as soon as possible.

Comment: I edited my answer with another solution allowing you to apply transformation before to saving data to BigQuery.